# import javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob; ERROR

Tags: android, sqlite, select, blob

```
 private void getMember() {
    Cursor mCursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM member", null);

    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
        listData.clear();
        if(mCursor.getCount() > 0){
            do {
                int id = mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex("id"));
                String title = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("title_name"));
                String name = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
                String surname = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("surname"));
                String nickname = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("nickname"));

                byte[] image = mCursor.getBlob(mCursor.getColumnIndex("image_data"));
                Blob image_data = new SerialBlob(image);

                listData.add(new MemberData(id, title, name, surname, nickname, image_data));
            }while (mCursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
}
```

I want to select image type Blob in database. But "SerialBlob" is error and "import javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob;" is error too.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You already have a byte array. Why do you want a different object?